# Creating a C# object in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm trying to submit data to a web service in my project. The data's in the form of several fields, so I'd rather create a single object and submit that. I know I can submit it as a JSON object, but I thought I'd seen code somewhere that would create a C# object on the JS side so that I could submit it to the web service.

Am I crazy, or what does this JS code look like?

Just to get everyone on the same page example-wise, let's say the C# class would look like this:

```
namespace NSTest
{
  [Serializable]
  public class ClassTest
  {
    public string ClassName;
    public int ClassValue;
  }
}
```

And the web service would look like this:

```
namespace NSTest
{
  public class WebServiceTest
  {
    [WebMethod]
    public void WSFunc(ClassTest test)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript variable would look like this:

```
var preparedParameters = {
    ClassName: "Some name",
    ClassValue: 10
};
```

But it depends how do you intend to call your web service, because you may have to wrap this variable inside some other object/array etc.?

Just for the better ease of client compatibility, have you maybe considered **WCF web services** because they are more configurable and provide bare format that doesn't need any wrapping etc.?

Comment: I haven't considered WCF yet since I haven't gotten any practice with it, but I'll look into it if I get some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
var test = {  
    ClassName:"classname",
    ClassValue:1
 };
```